# AdMob Implementation

Tags: android, admob

I am trying to implement AdMob into my Android app and I have 2 questions that I hope are straight forward. According to the quick start guide at: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start

1) I need to implement implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.0' - however if I am using google play services in my app, i.e. implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1' is this still required?

2) Once again in the guide it says to add the following to the Android manifest.xml:

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
android:value="[ADMOB_APP_ID]"/>
```

Probably a stupid question, but the APPLICATION_ID is the same in both cases correct? And in the value= do you actually leave the brackets? i.e:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.ca-app- pub-XXXXXXXXXX~XXXXXXXXXX"
    android:value="com.google.android.gms.ads.ca-app- pub-XXXXXXXXXX~XXXXXXXXXX"/>
/>
```

Comment: `play-services-ads` is a specific artifact for ads only but if you implement `play-services` that contains lots of artifact like auth, games, plus and many more. If you want to use ads version greater or equal then 17.0.0, you've to add applicationId in your manifest file as `meta data`.

Answer (score 1):

It must look like this:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXX~XXXXXXXXXX"/>
```

where `ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXX~XXXXXXXXXX` - is your Id

Answer (score 1):

1. If you use `com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1` in your application, then you dont need to include the ads package separately, as the play services is the main package which includes all the libraries.
2. `APPLICATION_ID` should stay as it is, it is to notify that the name of this value is `APPLICATION_ID`. You enter the value in the value part, without the braces. So it should look like this:

   ```
   <manifest>
       <application>
           <!-- Sample AdMob App ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
           <meta-data
               android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
               android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>
       </application>
   </manifest>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

First question's answer is  - No.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
```

Above line not required.

Second's answer is -

```
<meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
      android:value="ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXX~XXXXXXXXXX"/>
```

Meta tag should be like above and bracket is needed.

`ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXX~XXXXXXXXXX` - Your admob app id.